# Active directory account disabled

Tags: python, django, active-directory

I want add a account to AD by python ldap. by bellow code Account added to active directory maybe account status is disable:

```
import ldap
import sys
def create_user_activedirectory(username , password , name ):
    SCRIPT = 1
    ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2
    HOMEDIR_REQUIRED = 8
    PASSWD_NOTREQD = 32
    NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 512
    DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD = 65536
    TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION = 524288
    PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 8388608

    conn=ldap.open("192.168.10.41")
    conn.protocol_version=ldap.VERSION3
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    conn.simple_bind_s("administrator@hamed.local" , "XYZ")
    mymodlist = {
            "objectClass": ["top".encode('utf-8'), "person".encode('utf-8'), "organizationalPerson".encode('utf-8'), "user".encode('utf-8')],
            "cn": [str(username).encode('utf-8')],
            #"uid": [str(username).encode('utf-8')],
            "userPassword": [str(password).encode('iso-8859-1')],
            "userPrincipalName": [str(username+"@XaaS.local").encode('iso-8859-1')],
            "sAMAccountName": [str(username).encode('utf-8')],
            "givenName": [str(name).encode('iso-8859-1')],
            "sn": [str(name).encode('iso-8859-1')],
            "displayName": [str(name).encode('iso-8859-1')],
            #"userAccountControl": [NORMAL_ACCOUNT],
            "userAccountControl": [str(NORMAL_ACCOUNT).encode('utf-8')],
        }
    dn="CN="+username+",CN=Users,DC=XaaS,DC=local"
    conn.add_s(dn, ldap.modlist.addModlist(mymodlist))
```

by "userAccountControl": [NORMAL_ACCOUNT] attribute, i get bellow error:

```
{'info': '0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}
```

if Delete "userAccountControl": [NORMAL_ACCOUNT] attribute, Account Disabled.

Comment: Don't use str() on `userAccountControl` attribute, it expects a Decimal/Hexadecimal value. Please check if it helps!

Comment: Tnx for answer. but get this error: 'int' object han no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I suggested you to plainly use the value `NORMAL_ACCOUNT` as the value of userAccountControl attribute. I don't know how you can manage encoding of the same, as it is not a string value!